# What is wrong with this Autocomplete script?

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Here is my HTML page.

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" class="auto" name="search" autocomplete="off">
</form>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function($){
    $('.auto').autocomplete({
    source:'connect.php', 
    minLength:1
    });
});
</script>
```

Here is my connect.php

```
if(isset($_GET['term'])) {
  require "db.php";

  $con = mysqli_connect("$host","$user","$password","$db");

  if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

  $term = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['term']);
  $term = strtolower($term);
  $query = "SELECT `name` FROM `products` WHERE `name` LIKE '%$term%'";
  $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
  $return_array = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

        $return_array[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($return_array);
}
```

Using chrome tools to inspect the response, it goes as following:

```
[{"0":"MacBook Pro 13-inch","name":"MacBook Pro 13-inch"},{"0":"MacBook Pro 15-inch","name":"MacBook Pro 15-inch"},{"0":"MacBook Air 13-inch","name":"MacBook Air 13-inch"},{"0":"MacBook Air 11-inch","name":"MacBook Air 11-inch"},{"0":"iMac 21.5-inch","name":"iMac 21.5-inch"},{"0":"iMac 27-inch","name":"iMac 27-inch"},{"0":"Mac Pro Quad-Core","name":"Mac Pro Quad-Core"},{"0":"Mac Pro 6-Core","name":"Mac Pro 6-Core"}]
```

But on the page, I get  "No search results."

I have googled around a lot and I think it's to do with the way the json is output but I'm not sure. I don't wish to use an ajax method.

Please no PDO as I can only understand basic procedural code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As rodrigogq already pointed out, jQuery UI autocomplete accepts data in two forms,

Either an array of strings:

```
[ "value1", "value2" ]
```

Or an array of objects having label and value properties:

```
[  { label:"value1", value:0},  { label:"value2", value:1}, ]
```

---

You have two options: Modify the server side script to provide the proper response,

or

Modify the client side script to sanitize the server response.

Following is the later, according to the response you shared:

```
$(document).ready(function($){
  $('.auto').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      $.get('connect.php', { term: request.term }, function(data) {
        var matches = $.map($.parseJSON(data),function(obj){
          return obj.name;
        });
        response(matches);
      });
    }, 
    minLength:1
  });
});
```

Comment: With that block of code, I don't get "no search results" any more but nothing appears on the page either?

Comment: `["MacBook Pro 13-inch","MacBook Pro 15-inch","MacBook Air 13-inch","MacBook Air 11-inch","iMac 21.5-inch","iMac 27-inch","Mac Pro Quad-Core","Mac Pro 6-Core"]`

That is my response. I get no error this time but nothing appears on the page still?

Comment: @this is according to the response you shared in question, the objects should have a name property...

Comment: @AshleyBrown If you're getting the response you shared in comments, then it should work fine: see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u7xebd11/). So something else is going wrong. Have you linked to jQuery, followed by jQuery UI and it's CSS..? Do you get any errors in browsers console..?

Comment: Yeah I have them both linked. Do you have another method of contact besides this? Maybe using an IM or a screen share software we could  fix this problem a little quicker...

Comment: If we continue posting comments, StackOverflow will invite to move the discussion to it's own chat room... :D If you've linked jQuery followed by jQuery UI JS and CSS, then the script you've shared, and you're getting the response you mentioned in comments, then it should work..! Something is going wrong - Can you press `F12` and see if there are any errors..?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65883/discussion-between-ashley-brown-and-t-j).

Answer (score 0):

What does `$(document).ready(function($){` mean? It should be `$(document).ready(function(){` (mind the `$`).

Also, try sending the full url to your `source` option, like `http://www.yoursite.com/connect.php`.

**EDIT**

Also please read this: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

As you can see you either provide arrays as:

```
   [ "value1", "value2" ]
```

Or:

```
   [  { label:"value1", value:0},  { label:"value2", value:1}, ]
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function($){ <- Mine 
    $(document).ready(function($){ <- Yours


Where is the difference?

Comment: The source isn't the problem as you can clearly see that it's being posted fully...

Comment: @AshleyBrown the difference is the `$` passed as an argument to `function ()` in yours.

Comment: Your array is wrong format. according to http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source you need to provide a plain array or an label/value attributes.

Comment: @Alfonso I get it now since your edit ;). Okay, changed that... Obviously didn't make a difference but thank you.

Comment: @AshleyBrown follow this tutorial http://www.wowww.nl/2014/02/01/jquery-autocomplete-tutorial-php-mysql/ and pay attention how he sets the `a_json` and `a_json_row` variables.

Answer (score 0):

To give you an idea of what is going wrong: with your code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.auto').autocomplete({
        source:'test1.php',
        minLength:1
    });
});
```

and this dummy PHP file test1.php:

```
echo json_encode(array('alpha', 'alphabet', 'beta'));
```

autocompletion is working. So:, you have to change:

```
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $return_array[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($return_array);
```

into:

```
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $return_array[] = $row['name'];
    }
    echo json_encode($return_array);
```

Comment: Okay now it cleans up the JSON response a lot. However, still not working for me.. "no search results" ?
`["MacBook Pro 13-inch","MacBook Pro 15-inch","MacBook Air 13-inch","MacBook Air 11-inch","iMac 21.5-inch","iMac 27-inch","Mac Pro Quad-Core","Mac Pro 6-Core"]`
Heres what i get

Comment: No I didn't... Where should I be adding that?

Comment: What you get from PHP is OK. It's not nescessary to add it. I tried with your data, it works on my machine.

Comment: Sorry, at this point, I have no idea. I suggest that you first try with the example from the Jquery manual *with your data* coded in Javascript, just to check that it works independantly of the server part.

Comment: @M.Page I've no idea either, I already checked it in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u7xebd11/) and it works fine..! -_-